# Why doesn't the public repository added work for the pip install?

Tags: python, pip

I want to install a library, but it says it's nor available:

```
> pip install tensorflow-text==2.4.1
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.douban.com/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.4.1 (from versions: 2.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.4.1
```

However, tensorflow-text==2.4.1 is clearly present in the repository, as below shown:

```
https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.4.1/
```

I think the reason is the local index repository:
https://pypi.douban.com/simple/

It doesn't use the public python index repository. I remember there is a way to change the py index repository to use the public index. But I forgot how to make that change. How to edit so that it won't look for the local index repository:
https://pypi.douban.com/simple/

EDIT: Based on the linked answer I added a line into the config:

```
cat ~/.pip/pip.conf 
[global]
index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
extra-index-url = https://pypi.douban.com/simple/

[install]
trusted-host=pypi.douban.com
```

But I still got the same issue:

```
pip install tensorflow-text==2.4.1
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.douban.com/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.4.1 (from versions: 2.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.4.1
```

It nows looks for it in both repository, but still can't find it. Why is that?

Comment: Of course, if you're on a work server, it may be you don't have authorisation to change this, and the local repo is setup like that to retain control over what is installed.

Comment: @michjnich Please see my updated question, it got the same issue after my edition.

Comment: Could be you need to talk to your workplace about firewalls ...

Answer (score -1):

try this:
`pip install tensorflow-text`
a new version was released in May-21